# How can I get $.get in jquery to only return links and not all html?

Tags: jquery

How do I get `$.get` in jQuery to only return links from the target and not all html?

```
$.get( "http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biological-engineering/20-010j-introduction-to-bioengineering-be-010j-spring-2006/lecture-notes/", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

But I only want it to grab the pdf links and download the pdfs.

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biological-engineering/20-010j-introduction-to-bioengineering-be-010j-spring-2006/lecture-notes/

Comment: `.get()` doesnt work like that... Ajax will always return the full content of the target, unless you control the output of the target you will have to parse the returned html in full

Comment: Is there a way to parse it just for the links?

Comment: Use the solution suggested by bozdoz , assign the result to a variable and then parse the list yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead, and use a selector after the url, to get the links.

Here's a better example:

```
// this is not appended to anything
var holder = $('<div></div>');

// load the tags into the holder element
// note the 'a' selector after the url
holder.load('http://crazy-long-url.com a', function () {
    // data has loaded
    var links = holder[0].children;

    // links are the anchors within the holder
    // iterate over them to show the URLs
    for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('<li></li>').html(links[i].href)
        .appendTo('#links');
    } 
});
```

Alternatively, you could push the href values to an array:

```
var urls = [];
for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    urls.push(links[i].href);
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/H9tFG/) to see it in action.

Comment: how do i get it to just give me an array of all the pdf links? Wouldn't that insert it into a new <div>?

Comment: +1 for sharing this trick.. jQuery is amazing! The more i know it the bigger a fan i become..

Comment: Hey @user2491254, I've updated my answer to be more thorough, with a working example included.